# How to create a bitmap at run time in ASP.NET Core Web Application project

Tags: c#, asp.net, telegram, telegram-bot

How can I create a bitmap in my project?

I'm writing C# code of a telegram bot using Telegram API.

I would like to generate an image at run time and send it to someone, but I can't create a bitmap because it needs System.Drawing reference and I can't add references because there is no possibility to do it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B62Um.png